# Looping no request

Tags: python, request

Como eu poderia fazer um looping para trazer informações do request de uma lista de coordenadas de um csv e levar o resultado para outro csv?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

parametro = dict(latitude=-23.512294, longitude=-46.667259, status=1, lista=1, limite=96, acessibilidade='')

r = requests.post('https://www.banco24horas.com.br/index/busca-json-terminal', data=parametro)

df = r.json()
display(df)
```

Comment: Olha -  dizer como se grava um CSV a partir do grosso desses dados é relativamente fácil - , mas se você (ou vocês) tiverem qualquer outra necessidade de programação por ai, eu sugiro estudar a linguagem Python de forma mais sistemática por alguns dias

Answer (score 0):

O valor devolvido após feit a a requisição não é um "CSV" - (CSVs é um nome genérico para um tipo de arquivo, nem é um formato de dados que exista na memória).

De qualquer forma, uma vez que você já está usando Pandas, gravar um arquivo CSV a partir da chave `detalhes` dessa resposta é trivial. (A resposta não retorna apenas uma lista com informações sobre as ATMs, há outros campos também):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

parametro = dict(latitude=-23.512294, longitude=-46.667259, status=1, lista=1, limite=96, acessibilidade='')

r = requests.post('https://www.banco24horas.com.br/index/busca-json-terminal', data=parametro)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['detalhes']
df.to_csv('meu_arquivo.csv')
```

A chama `.to_csv` do Pandas já cria o arquivo e grava todos os dados serializados de forma correta.